check if file exists that has digits in it
I have following code:
config_path="mypath/"
outD="outDir/"

for doms in Germ500 Port500 Spai500;do
    echo "animating for: ${doms}"
    config_name="${doms}_config.toml"
    # Check if the Germ500_titt_20240903T0000_animation.html exists, otherwise make new
    # 
    [ ! -f "${outD}${doms}_titt_[????????]T[????]_animation.html" ] && echo "File does not exist: make new" || echo "${outD}${doms}_titt_[????????]T[????]_animation.html exist"

done

How can I fix the command?
I tried the following:
[ ! -f "${outD}${doms}_titt_[0-9]{8}T[0-9]{4}_animation.html" ] && echo "File does not exist: make new" || echo "${outD}${doms}_titt_[????????]T[????]_animation.html exist"

@markp-fuso no, it won't be an error, because it is quoted. No expansion happens with quoting. That also means that it will not match if there's only a single file name (unless the file name has literal question marks in it) – again: no glob expansion happens due to the quotes

if you know there will always be 0 or 1 instances of the file you could remove the brackets and quotes, leaving you with [ ! -f ${doms}_titt_????????T????_animation.html ]; keep in mind this will generate an error if you have more than 1 match

The wildcard [????????]T[????] is equivalent to [?]T[?] (character classes only match a single character), which will only match the literal filename ?T?. If you want to match digits, you must use [0-9], i.e. [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]T[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].
But test -f ([ -f … ]) can only handle a single path. Quoting an expression will prevent glob expansion, but even if the glob were expanded, your script would break because, again, -f only handles a single path.
Can I interest you in a find-based solution instead?
if test "$(find "$outD" -maxdepth 1 -name "${doms}_titt_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]T[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]_animation.html" -print -quit)"; then
  echo 'file matching pattern exists'
else
  echo 'no file matching pattern found'
fi

or a loop-based one?
for file in "$outD/${doms}_titt_"[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]T[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]_animation.html; do
  if test -f "$file"; then
    echo "file $file exists"
  else
    echo "no file matching pattern found"
  fi
  break
done

It's not bullet proof and could lead to unexpected results if you have a file with the literal pattern as name.
Find additional (portable or bash-only) solutions in Test whether a glob has any matches in Bash

Works! is there a way to get that exact filename if it exist?
if test "$(find "$outD" -maxdepth 1 -name "${doms}_titt_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]T[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]_animation.html" -print -quit)"; then   echo 'file $File exists' else   echo 'no file matching pattern found' fi

@YoKu I have updated the answer to include another option which gives access to the file name. Note that you could simply store the output of find to a variable and then check that variable for non-zero content, that should give you the same result.
